# Symfony2: Edit form issue with the drop downs

Tags: php, symfony

I am having a problem in auto filling a drop down list in edit form. The form having the other text box(Article Title) and one drop down(Duration) filling the correct value but not the country and state drop down is working. Although i am passing the values but its not reflecting in the form.

Here is my controller function:

```
public function addtrailsAction(Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

  // print_r($_POST);
   $id = $request->get('trailid');

   $userForm = new BidUserRequest();
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $memberId = $user->getId();
    $table = 'BidUser';
    //Get user detail by logged in member.
    $userDetail = $em->getRepository('AdventureLoginBundle:BidMember')->getDetailByMemberId($memberId,$table);

    $userid =$this->getUser()->getId();

    $clicknblog = $this->get('adventure_bridge.clicknblog');
    $counttrail= $clicknblog->checkusertrails($userid,$id);

    foreach ($counttrail as $value) {
    }
    if($value > 0 ){
         $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                    'warning', 'Trail already added.');
              return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('adventure_bidding_user_view_trails'));
    }
    else{
     $clicknblog = $this->get('adventure_bridge.clicknblog');
     //$state= $clicknblog->getState('');
     //$country= $userForm->getCountry();
     $continent= $clicknblog->getCountries('');
     $activity= $clicknblog->getArticle($id);
     foreach ($activity as $value) {
         $name = $value['articleTitle'];
         $durationMax = $value['durationMax'];
         $zone = $value['zone'];
         $state = $value['state'];
         $country = $value['country'];
        //$activity = $value['typeOfActivity'];
     }
        var_dump($activity); // Printing all the values but state and country is not reflecting in the form
    //   $userForm->setActivity($activity);
     $userForm->setCountry($country);$userForm->setState($state);
     $userForm->setDay($durationMax);
     $userForm->setZone($zone);
     $userForm->setName($name);
     $userForm->setTeam(0);
     $requestForm = $this->createForm(new RequestUserType(), $userForm);
        var_dump($userForm); //Printing all the values but state and country is not reflecting in the form
        die();
    // $requestForm->remove('country');

        return $this->render('AdventureBiddingBundle:User:trailRequestUser.html.twig', array(
        'activity' => $activity,
        'state' => $state,
        //'country' => $country,
        'continent' => $continent,
        'Form' => $requestForm->createView()

    ));


    }
}
```

Where is the problem exists, please help. I am a newbie..

**Update:** My first `var_dump` Result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
["id"]=>
string(1) "5"
["durationMax"]=>
string(1) "2"
["articleTitle"]=>
string(40) "Paramotoring with camp Tikkling, Gurgaon"
["difficulty"]=>
string(5) "basic"
["zone"]=>
string(5) "north"
["continent"]=>
string(1) "1"
["country"]=>
string(3) "356"
["state"]=>
string(7) "Haryana"
 }
}
```

Comment: When you say in your comments : 'state and country is not reflecting in the form, do you mean they are null ? Can you show the exact var_dump of `$activity` ?

Comment: They are not null in the var_dump, i updated my question from the `var_dump` of `$activity`

Comment: And have you got any errors ? If you use the Symfony toolbar, you should be able to see the SQL request and operations rejected

Comment: It is showing 5 queries executed and 1 invalid entity....what does it mean?

Comment: The association Adventure\BiddingBundle\Entity\continents#countries refers to the owning side field Adventure\BiddingBundle\Entity\countries#continent which is not defined as association, but as field.
The association Adventure\BiddingBundle\Entity\continents#countries refers to the owning side field Adventure\BiddingBundle\Entity\countries#continent which does not exist.

Comment: Ok, your problem is in your relation between the two Continent and Country entities. Can you show them please ? It's in your annotation that there is a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78995/discussion-between-anonymus-and-guillaume-fache).